# How to store data into model using fromJson in flutter firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I'm working on a flutter project. I'm trying to create a function that gets snapshot from Firebase document and stores it into userData model using fromJson function.

Here's my **User.dart**

```
class UserData {
  // final String uid;
  final String usn;
  final String fullName;
  final int? sem;
  final String branch;
  final String section;

  UserData({
    required this.usn,
    required this.fullName,
    required this.sem,
    required this.branch,
    required this.section,
  });

  factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserData(
        usn: json['usn'],
        fullName: json['fullName'],
        sem: json['sem'],
        branch: json['branch'],
        section: json['section']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'usn': usn,
      'fullName': fullName,
      'sem': sem,
      'branch': branch,
      'section': section
    };
  }
}
```

In my **database.dart**
I want to create a Stream function in it to map to fromJson
Here's what I have tried

```
 Stream<UserData?> curUserData() {
    return _db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).snapshots()
    .map((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => UserData.fromJson(snapshot.data()));
  }
```

Can anyone rectify the function?

I am getting error from above function.

Comment: What is the error? If you show the error it might be easier to find and solve the problem

Comment: Error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is just wrong type assertion. Try this:
Change `DocumentSnapshot` for `DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```
 Stream<UserData?> curUserData() {
    return _db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).snapshots()
    .map((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) => UserData.fromDocument(snapshot.data()!));
  }
```

Comment: I cannot use DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> either in class or in my database.dart , I need real time updates from firestore , I need to use Stream

Comment: I edit the answer because I forgot to edit the code. If it doesn't work, the other answer might work for you.

Comment: The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. I'am still getting error.

Comment: Just add a ```!``` sign after ```snapshot.data()``` : ```snapshot.data()!```.

Comment: Awesome that worked , thank you so much guys , both of you @NelsomThiago and @Jomon for helping me,  adding  right mark to @Nelson's answer , @Nelson can please edit the code and add that `!` to your answer ?.

Answer (score 0):

This example is for my case with `cloud_firestore: ^3.1.7`:

```
getLastStageNumber() async {

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await stagesRef
        .orderBy('stage_number', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .get();
    StageMod stageMod;
    if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      stageMod = StageMod.fromJson(
          querySnapshot.docs.first.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>);
      lastStageNumber = stageMod.stageNumber;
    }
  }
```